# Poetry: create a package from a part of a project

Tags: python-poetry

I am using Poetry to build some package. For simplicity sake the structure of the repository looks something like this:

```
my_package
    pyproject.toml
    service
        client
            client.py
            data.py
            __init__.py
        __init__.py
```

But I want the package is named `my_package_client` and includes just `client` directory. So that after installation I could import like this:

```
from my_package_client import Client
```

I tried to write this in pyproject.toml:

```
name = "my_project_client"
packages = [
    {include = "client", from = "service"}
]
```

But obviously after installation I only can import this way:

```
from service.client import Client
```

Comment: I added an answer below, but unfortunately I didn't have time to fully test it. Let me know if this works or helps. If not, I can either fix it or remove it. Let me know.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no way to "alias" the package name in Poetry. I worked around this by adding an extra package between `service` and `client`, like this:

```
my_package
    pyproject.toml
    service
        my_project_client
            client
                client.py
                data.py
                __init__.py
            __init__.py
```

pyproject.toml (note dashes vs. underscores):

```
name = "my-project-client"
packages = [
    {include = "my_project_client", from = "service"}
]
```

Add this to the `__init__.py` of `my_project_client` to get the namespace you want:

```py
from .client import Client
```

After publishing to PyPI, install the package in a different repo:

```sh
pip install my-project-client
```

Then you can import like this:

```py
from my_project_client import Client
```